# Scope issue, anonymous function access variable above?

Tags: javascript

I was under the impression that an anonymous function could access variables defined above it?

This function is within a variable, so it shouldn't run before the variable i'm trying to access is defined, because of course function's are run before variables within the compiler from my understanding.

```
var sidebar = {};
sidebar['locations'] = map.getElementsByClassName('google-map-locations')[0];

// Generate location links function
var addLocationLinks = function(i) {

  // Append the links to the HTML.
  console.log(sidebar['locations']); // undefined
};
for (var i in this.options.locations) {
  addLocationLinks.call(this, i);
}
```

**Edit:**

```
build() {
  const _ = this;

  _.map = new google.maps.Map(_.options.container, {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(_.options.locations[0].lat, _.options.locations[0].lng),
    zoom: 16
  });

  // This loop will create markers but also check if images exist for custom markers. 
  for(var i in _.options.locations) {
    _.create_marker.call(_, _.options.locations[i], i); // Create marker
  }

  // Due to checking images exist we must ensure the above has completed before continuing, 
  // keep on checking saved markers equal locations
  (function markers_created() {
    const _ = this;

    if((this.options.locations).length !== this.markers.length) {
      setTimeout(markers_created.bind(this), 5);
      return;
    }
    // Markers have been added, continue with the plugin execution
    _.handle_sidebar.call(_);
  }.call(_));
}

// This next function will basically use an array's data to add some additional HTML, should be unrelated to the Google Maps API
  handle_sidebar(x) {
    const _ = this;

    // Generate the sidebar and add it to the DOM
    if ((_.options.container).getElementsByClassName('google-map-sidebar').length === 0) {

      var sidebar = { 
        map: (_.options.container).firstChild // Get the DIV the map is within before adding more.
      };

      // Sidebar doesn't exist yet, create it.
      (function() {
        const container = _.options.container;

        // Construct most HTML as a string, easier to read..
        var html = '<section class="google-map-sidebar">';
        html +=      '<span class="google-map-toggle"></span>';
        html +=      '<div class="google-map-container">';
        html +=        '<div class="google-map-main>';
        html +=          '<h3>Contact</h3>';  
        html +=          '<ul class="google-map-locations"></ul>'
        html +=        '</div>';
        html +=      '</div>';
        html +=    '</section>';

        // Append the HTML
        container.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html);

        // Maintain reference to HTMLElements
        sidebar['toggle'] = container.getElementsByClassName('google-map-toggle')[0];
        sidebar['content'] = container.getElementsByClassName('google-map-container')[0];
        sidebar['home'] = container.getElementsByClassName('google-map-main')[0];
        sidebar['locations'] = container.getElementsByClassName('google-map-locations')[0];

        // Generate location links function
        var addLocationLinks = function(i) {
          var link = document.createElement('a');
          link.title = _.options.locations[i].name;
          link.innerHTML = _.options.locations[i].name;
          link.classList.add((_.options.locations[i].type === undefined) ? 'showroom' : _.options.locations[i].type);
          link.addEventListener('click', function() {
            _.handle_sidebar(i);
          });

          // Append the links to the HTML.
          console.log(sidebar['locations']);
          sidebar['locations'].appendChild(link);
        };
        for (var i in _.options.locations) {
          addLocationLinks.call(_, i);
        }
      }.call(_));

      // Add event listeners
      sidebar['toggle'].addEventListener('click', function() {
        sidebar['toggle'].classList.toggle('hide');
        sidebar['map'].classList.toggle('hide');
      });


      // Add sidebar enabled class to map
      sidebar['map'].classList.add('sidebar_enabled');

      // Finished adding the initial sidebar
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit 2:**

Sorry about the waste of time, it was due to the `html` string missing a double quote and not being converted to correct HTML!

Comment: Can you add a `console.log(sidebar['locations'])` immediately after you assign it? My only hunch is that when you're querying the DOM the map isn't fully rendered yet.

Comment: @wholevinski damn your right, this is also undefined. This should be assigned already though :S

Comment: OK, sweet. I'm guessing you're using google maps API judging by the classname then. So I'd either 1. make that DOM query dynamic inside of addLocationLinks or 2. wait to assign that variable inside a "map finished loading" event handler offered by the google maps API.

Comment: The code above however isn't connected to the Google Maps API, i'm appending an extra div to the DOM so it should be un-related?

Comment: Hm, ok, would you mind posting a little bit more code then? Is map the div that's being added dynamically?

Comment: @wholevinski added more code, should be commented enough to see what's going on. `_` will retain the scope of the class.

Comment: @wholevinski yeah sorry mate, just noticed the `html` string was missing a double quote when I added a class, so the HTML wasn't being added correctly!

Comment: Sweet! Glad you figured it out, enjoy!